# String replace in many the tables for some fields?

Tags: mysql, string, replace

I have a drupal based site (CCK+Views+Taxonomy) with a huge amount of text content. Now consider I would like to convert all the "W" in the content with "w", I have no idea what tables to touch or what fields in those tables, I just know that I want all the "W"s in the site (it's content I mean, database) to be replaced with "w"s, any insights ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In drupal, use Scanner module which has exactly that functionality.
Generally speaking, one should write a script to accomplish the task.